# How do I extract strings between the substrings at their first instance (readable string at all times)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am working on a hobby project where I need to extract certain info between two substrings and there may be more than one occurrence.

---

Example:
Sample Text:

```
import re
s = "FooFoo name=JohnSmith and BarBar name=JackSmith"
start="name="
end="Smith"
```

Sample Code:

```
result = re.findall('name=(.*)Smith', s)
```

Sample Output: result array with all extracted substrings

```
print(result)
>>>['John', 'Jack']
```

---

I have tried regex and str.sub which have worked, but I have had trouble to put my search results into an array that can be called back later. I can post my attempted solutions if they help at all.
NOTE: It should only start the substring at the first occurrence of Start and end at the first occurrence of End, and then continue parsing the string after that location (don't want repeats or nested substrings)

PS: I am unsure of the encoding of the input, would there be a way to make sure it is always in a readable format for this method?
Ex:

```
MyString.decode() or MyString.encode('utf-8') or
MyString.encode('ascii','ignore') or unicodedata.normalize(MyString)?
```

Please let me know and any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: what you mean by *put my search results into an array that can be called back later* ?

Comment: In addition to Kasra's question, you should probably reword your question title and clarify the *make sure it is always in a readable format* part. If you cannot describe the problem, then at least give an example.

Comment: @Jerry yes , and also im wondering that how there is 3 answer here ? and no one of them dont gave a true and complete solution to all of questions !!!!

Comment: @Kasra That's the problem with stackoverflow. Lots of people answering as fast as they can to get the points rather than attending the OP's problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a non-greedy match:

```
In [7]: result = re.findall('name=(.*?)Smith', s)
                                     ↑ THIS

In [8]: result
Out[8]: ['John', 'Jack']
```

Without the `?`, the `*` grabs *as many* characters as it can. As a result, the match starts at the first `=name` and ends at the last `Smith`.

With the `?`, the `*` grabs *as few* characters as it can, resulting in separate matches for each `name=`/`Smith` pair.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Hey! This is exactly what I needed! I had trouble with that one missing question mark and also had to cancel out another one that I had in the 2nd substring.

This is exactly what I was looking for, :D Thanks so much!